# How to exchange string content in a text file in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a text file as follows:

```
1 ... 3 4 2    
2 ... 3 21 4  
3 ... 6 4 21 15  
4 ... 14 21 12
```

I want to edit these strings, so that numbers after dotted parts to be splitted corresponding to the first number of each string. For example,

```
1  
2 1  
3 1 2  
4 1 2 3  
...  
21 3 4
```

How can I do this?
Note: I obtain the first number group from a text file and edit it string by string. After that, I have written edited strings to the text file. In light of this, sample part of my code to obtain the first number group is provided as below:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < existingLines.Length; i++)
        {
            var split = existingLines[i].Split('\t');
            var act = i - 1;
            var sc1 = int.Parse(split[6]);
            var sc2 = int.Parse(split[7]);
            appendedLines.Add(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", act, sc1, sc2));
        }
```

Comment: You don't explain how the result is generated so it's impossible to help. Besides, the title seems to have no relation to the question text

Comment: How are you computing your results? I can't figure out how you want to process your numbers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, numbers are taken from an existing text file.

Comment: @act that's not what I meant - why `4 1 2 3 ? What logic produces this line? Or `21 3 4` ? `after dotted parts to be splitted corresponding to the first number of each string` doesn't make any sense

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, "1, 2, 3, 4" (the first character of each line) denotes number of the corresponding line (act = i - 1). The remaining numbers do not follow any logical pattern, they are just the output of the text file that I use as an input. However, they have to be splitted according to line number (act) .

Comment: what sort of logic gets you from what you have in the file to your example

Comment: @act there's no 2 in the second line apart from the line number. Where did `2 1` come from in the result? Unless you explain how the logic, no-one can help you.

Comment: he's making my head hurt trying to figure out the logic on my own

Comment: Are you having trouble with (1) the file reading or writing? (2) The string processing? (But you know about `String.split()`) (3) The algorithmic logic?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I wrote 21 to be able to explain what I try to achieve. Actually, these numbers represent activities of a project. The first number in each line (from top to bottom) "1, 2, 3, 4, ...., 21" represents the activity number. The remaining numbers in each line (ex: "3, 4, 2" in the first line) denotes the successor activities to the corresponding one.
I am trying to write predecessor of each activity instead of successor. Hence, I have to split "3, 4, 2" -or any number in each line- according to corresponding activity.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, string.split() helps me to edit a string in itself. According to the example given below,
1 3 4 2 
I need to edit the third, the forth and the second strings and add these strings "1" as a character.

Comment: @act what you just described is completely unrelated to the question, any of the previous comments, splitting or even text processing. You are asking how to find ancestors for an activity when you have a list of children for each activity. This is graph processing. I suggest you make a separate question asking for what you really want. This question can't be salvaged

Comment: @act: you should update your question to explain the meaning of those numbers, as your 'activities' comment describes. Also note that the `21` line in your example output is missing a `2`.

Answer (score 2):

This LINQ code should get you started

```
        string path = "c:\\temp\\test.txt";

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            var lines = new List<IEnumerable<int>>();

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                lines.Add(sr.ReadLine().Split(new[] { '.', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => int.Parse(x)));
            }

            foreach (var node in lines.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x))
            {
                var predecessors = lines.Where(x => x.Skip(1).Contains(node))
                    .Select(x => x.First())
                    .OrderBy(x => x);

                Console.WriteLine(node + " " + string.Join(" ", predecessors));
            }
        }
```

Output

```
2 1
3 1 2
4 1 2 3
6 3
12 4
14 4
15 3
21 2 3 4
```

Comment: It's a bit intentionnal. ;) It's my morning warmup.  If I get downvoted I will remove it.

Comment: For goodness sake, no! You could be nice and break it down though.

Comment: I like it. It's illustrative of something.